# Why can't I install the pracma package on R on macOS Sierra?

Tags: r

I am somehow unable to install the `pracma` package on R on macOS Sierra.
Why is this the case?

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> install.packages('pracma')
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Secure CRAN mirrors 

 1: 0-Cloud [https]                   2: Algeria [https]                
 3: Australia (Canberra) [https]      4: Australia (Melbourne 1) [https]
 5: Australia (Melbourne 2) [https]   6: Australia (Perth) [https]      
 7: Austria [https]                   8: Belgium (Ghent) [https]        
 9: Brazil (RJ) [https]              10: Brazil (SP 1) [https]          
11: Bulgaria [https]                 12: Chile 1 [https]                
13: China (Lanzhou) [https]          14: Colombia (Cali) [https]        
15: Czech Republic [https]           16: Denmark [https]                
17: Estonia [https]                  18: France (Lyon 1) [https]        
19: France (Lyon 2) [https]          20: France (Marseille) [https]     
21: France (Montpellier) [https]     22: France (Paris 2) [https]       
23: Germany (Göttingen) [https]      24: Germany (Münster) [https]      
25: Greece [https]                   26: Iceland [https]                
27: Indonesia (Jakarta) [https]      28: Ireland [https]                
29: Italy (Padua) [https]            30: Japan (Tokyo) [https]          
31: Malaysia [https]                 32: Mexico (Mexico City) [https]   
33: Norway [https]                   34: Philippines [https]            
35: Serbia [https]                   36: Spain (A Coruña) [https]       
37: Spain (Madrid) [https]           38: Sweden [https]                 
39: Switzerland [https]              40: Turkey (Denizli) [https]       
41: Turkey (Mersin) [https]          42: UK (Bristol) [https]           
43: UK (Cambridge) [https]           44: UK (London 1) [https]          
45: USA (CA 1) [https]               46: USA (IA) [https]               
47: USA (KS) [https]                 48: USA (MI 1) [https]             
49: USA (OR) [https]                 50: USA (TN) [https]               
51: USA (TX 1) [https]               52: Vietnam [https]                
53: (other mirrors)                  

Selection: 45
trying URL 'https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/pracma_2.0.7.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1088304 bytes (1.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.0 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/96/q59q0w591_z1b1g7zqcby3p80000gn/T//RtmprmmdzT/downloaded_packages
Warning message:
In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so
  Reason: image not found
>
```